# can't setup kubernetes using a certificate as x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: networking, kubernetes, x509

I am trying to secure kubernetes, I have a master and a minion which both work, then I followed the guide at http://rootsquash.com/2016/05/10/securing-the-kubernetes-api/

I now have the running master which can be access through https but I was getting a "Unauthorized" error so I created a certificate for myself through the same process I did for the minion, created a p12 file which then imported into firefox, I restarted the browser and was prompted to authenticate with a certificate, I used the one I just imported and was presented with:

```
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "2",
  "gitVersion": "v1.2.0",
  "gitCommit": "ec7364b6e3b155e78086018aa644057edbe196e5",
  "gitTreeState": "clean"
}
```

So I can now connect through the browser, then I go setup the minion and restart the service and when I check the status what I get is

```
kubelet[1655]: E1019 14:53:26.962906    1655 event.go:202] Unable to write event: 'x509: certificate signed by unknown authority' (may retry after sleeping)
```

I tried installing the root CA certificate I created in both the master and minion but that did not work so I thought maybe the certificate is corrupted, so using the same certificate the minion is using I did

```
 curl -k --key /srv/kubernetes/${HOSTNAME}.key  --cert /srv/kubernetes/${HOSTNAME}.crt  --cacert /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt https://kubernetes.master:6443/version
```

And got the same

```
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "2",
  "gitVersion": "v1.2.0",
  "gitCommit": "ec7364b6e3b155e78086018aa644057edbe196e5",
  "gitTreeState": "clean"
}
```

So the master is obviously rejecting my certificate for some other reason as using the certificate in curl works just fine, I been doing some googling but have not been able to fix this issue so far with what I have found, can anyone point me in the right direction?

My setup is on cent os minimal and the code used to generate the config file is below

```
kubectl config set-cluster my_cluster --server=https://kubernetes.master:6443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
kubectl config unset clusters
kubectl config set-cluster my_cluster --certificate-authority=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt --embed-certs=true --server=https://kubernetes.master:6443
kubectl config set-credentials minion --client-certificate=/srv/kubernetes/minion.one.crt --client-key=/srv/kubernetes/minion.one.key --embed-certs=true --token=59qbOTrcPcdSEgz1EZ0jOznJQ7uOYEsO
kubectl config set-context service-account-context --cluster=my_cluster --user=minion
kubectl config use-context service-account-context
```

[update]

Upon further checking it may well not even be related to the certificate or the tls handshake, I ran 
    systemctl status -l kubelet.service
And got the following

```
Oct 19 16:11:58 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:58.683943   13120 manager.go:123] Starting to sync pod status with apiserver
Oct 19 16:11:58 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:58.683958   13120 kubelet.go:2372] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
Oct 19 16:11:58 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:58.683967   13120 kubelet.go:2381] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
Oct 19 16:11:58 minion.one kubelet[13120]: E1019 16:11:58.687984   13120 event.go:202] Unable to write event: 'Post https://kubernetes.master:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority' (may retry after sleeping)
Oct 19 16:11:58 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:58.930635   13120 factory.go:233] Registering Docker factory
Oct 19 16:11:58 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:58.930995   13120 factory.go:97] Registering Raw factory
Oct 19 16:11:59 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:59.063535   13120 manager.go:1003] Started watching for new ooms in manager
Oct 19 16:11:59 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:59.063556   13120 oomparser.go:198] OOM parser using kernel log file: "/var/log/messages"
Oct 19 16:11:59 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:59.063885   13120 manager.go:256] Starting recovery of all containers
Oct 19 16:11:59 minion.one kubelet[13120]: I1019 16:11:59.090785   13120 manager.go:261] Recovery completed
```

Could the first error

```
skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]
```

Be causing the later issues with the certificate?

Trying to figure out where that error comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this script which installs version 1.4

```
rm -f /etc/hostname
rm -f /etc/hosts
rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network
cat <<EOF > /etc/hostname
${HOSTNAME}
EOF
cat <<EOF > /etc/sysconfig/network
HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME}
EOF
cat <<EOF > /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   ${HOSTNAME} localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
${KUBERMASTER} kubernetes.vetology.net
EOF
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
yum -y update
cat <<EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=http://yum.kubernetes.io/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
setenforce 0
yum install -y docker kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni
systemctl enable docker && systemctl start docker
systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet
kubeadm init
```

All is working now.